# How do I correctly override a statically typed method with multiple @overloads (ArgumentParser.parse_args)

Tags: python, inheritance, mypy

I am trying to extend `argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args`, but `mypy` tells me I am doing it wrong:

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser, Namespace
from typing import Sequence


class MyArgumentParser(ArgumentParser):

    def parse_args(
        self,
        args: Sequence[str] = None,
        namespace: Namespace = None,
    ) -> Namespace:
        parsed_args = super().parse_args(args, namespace)
        # process parsed_args
        return parsed_args
```

I am getting these errors:

```
Signature of "parse_args" incompatible with supertype "ArgumentParser"
    Superclass:
        @overload
        def parse_args(self, args: Optional[Sequence[str]] = ...) -> Namespace
        @overload
        def parse_args(self, args: Optional[Sequence[str]], namespace: None) -> Namespace
        @overload
        def [_N] parse_args(self, args: Optional[Sequence[str]], namespace: _N) -> _N
        @overload
        def parse_args(self, *, namespace: None) -> Namespace
        @overload
        def [_N] parse_args(self, *, namespace: _N) -> _N
    Subclass:
        def parse_args(self, args: Optional[Sequence[str]] = ..., namespace: Optional[Namespace] = ...) -> Namespace
```

I have read https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/class_basics.html#overriding-statically-typed-methods, but still, a number of things are unclear to me:

- Where are these five different method signatures coming from? I can only find a single relevant implementation, here:
  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f20ca766fe404a20daea29230f161a0eb71bb489/Lib/argparse.py#L1843
- Do I have to match *one* of these signatures, or *all of them* (using some kind of  superset)?
- Why is `namespace` not optional for all of the signatures, although it clearly is in the above implementation?
- What is `_N`?

Comment: I have found the source of the overloads in `typeshed`, which answers the first question: https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/494481a0aed2ef0e00bbe190476ace0b8261bce6/stdlib/argparse.pyi#L128-L137

Comment: This is also where `_N` is defined: https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/494481a0aed2ef0e00bbe190476ace0b8261bce6/stdlib/argparse.pyi#L2-L7

Comment: `_N` is a variable defined in typeshed which can be any python `object`.

Comment: You might want to *focus* on individual points instead of having 4+1 questions in one. Aside from making it easier to answer and matching [ask], it would allow to give some more details or clarity on each point – e.g. why you think ``namespace`` isn't optional in any of the signatures.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thanks fot the hints. I fixed the question - I meant "for *all* of the signatures". I think the title of the question is what I would like answered, and anyone who answers can guide their answer by my subquestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After learning

- that the five `@overload`s are coming from [`typeshed`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/494481a0aed2ef0e00bbe190476ace0b8261bce6/stdlib/argparse.pyi#L128-L137), not from `argparse` itself,
- that `_N` is a placeholder allowing multiple use of an (unknown) variable type (e.g., output type dependent on input type),
- that an optional argument does not have to be optional in each of the `@overload`s, and
- that it is not sufficient to match just *some* superset of all overloads, but that one needs to reproduce the smallest set of constraints (thanks, @hussic),

I had still hoped that the following works:

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser, Namespace
from typing import Sequence, TypeVar

_N = TypeVar("_N")

class MyArgumentParser(ArgumentParser):
    def parse_args(
        self, args: Sequence[str] = None, namespace: _N = None
    ) -> _N | Namespace:
        return super().parse_args(args, namespace)
```

but of course it does not (see below).

```
Signature of "parse_args" incompatible with supertype "ArgumentParser"
    Superclass:
        @overload
        def parse_args(self, args: Optional[Sequence[str]] = ...) -> Namespace
        @overload
        def parse_args(self, args: Optional[Sequence[str]], namespace: None) -> Namespace
        @overload
        def [_N] parse_args(self, args: Optional[Sequence[str]], namespace: _N) -> _N
        @overload
        def parse_args(self, *, namespace: None) -> Namespace
        @overload
        def [_N] parse_args(self, *, namespace: _N) -> _N
    Subclass:
        def [_N] parse_args(self, args: Optional[Sequence[str]] = ..., namespace: Optional[_N] = ...) -> Union[_N, Namespace]
```

What does work is this:

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser, Namespace
from typing import Sequence, TypeVar, overload

_N = TypeVar("_N")


class MyArgumentParser(ArgumentParser):
    # https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/494481a0/stdlib/argparse.pyi#L128-L137
    @overload
    def parse_args(self, args: Sequence[str] | None = ...) -> Namespace:
        ...

    @overload
    def parse_args(self, args: Sequence[str] | None, namespace: None) -> Namespace:  # type: ignore[misc]
        ...

    @overload
    def parse_args(self, args: Sequence[str] | None, namespace: _N) -> _N:
        ...

    @overload
    def parse_args(self, *, namespace: None) -> Namespace:  # type: ignore[misc]
        ...

    @overload
    def parse_args(self, *, namespace: _N) -> _N:
        ...

    def parse_args(
        self, args: Sequence[str] = None, namespace: _N = None
    ) -> _N | Namespace:
        return super().parse_args(args, namespace)
```

which I find just a *tiny* bit too verbose, though.

I wonder if there are solutions where I don't have to repeat all `@overload`s.

---

To see why the first solution does not work, consider

```py
"""Demonstrate bug."""
from typing import Any, TypeVar, overload

_N = TypeVar("_N", int, float)


class Base:
    """Base class."""

    @overload
    def fun(self, var: None) -> str:
        ...

    @overload
    def fun(self, var: _N) -> _N:
        ...

    def fun(self, var: _N = None) -> _N | str:
        """Return var or "NaN"."""
        if var is None:
            return "NaN"
        return var


class Class1(Base):
    """My class."""

    def fun(self, var: _N = None) -> _N | str:
        """Return var or "None"."""
        return super().fun(var)


class Class2(Base):
    """My class."""

    @overload
    def fun(self, var: None) -> str:
        ...

    @overload
    def fun(self, var: _N) -> _N:
        ...

    def fun(self, var: _N = None) -> _N | str:
        """Return var or "None"."""
        return super().fun(var)


class Class3(Base):
    """My class."""

    def fun(self, var: Any = None) -> Any:
        """Return var or "None"."""
        return super().fun(var)
```

While it is clear that `Base.fun` returns `str` *only* if `var` is `None`, the same cannot be said from the signature of `Class1.fun`. So it seems one needs to replicate the complete set of `@overload`s such as in `Class2.fun`, unless one finds a smarter solution (compare @hussic's `TypeVar("T", int, str)` example) - in which case this should probably be merged into the corresponding package/`typeshed` directly. `Class3.fun` is another workaround that somewhat always works.

Comment: Your working solution with overload does not work here. I get 2 Mypy errors. It works only if you change the signature of real function with `def parse_args(self, args=None, namespace=None):`

Comment: @hussic you mean the third code snippet, the one with the GitHub link? What kind of errors are you getting? I am getting none in mypy `0.931` on Python `3.10.2`.

Comment: Yes, now I understand why: I use mypy --strict. See here: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=0.930&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=d3f40732c3df4d618d5f507b6752c010

Comment: Ah, I see. This is because `mypy --strict` does not like `args: Sequence[str] = None` etc. In non-strict mode, it infers `Optional[Sequence[str]]` - but apparently not so in strict mode. You can fix these errors by using `self, args: Sequence[str] | None = None, namespace: _N | None = None` as line 31: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=0.931&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=29f7d1b8472cb18e1f43b73be788e12d

Comment: Thank. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

All signatures of superclass must be matched. Example:

```
class A:
    @overload
    def f(self, a: int) -> int: ...
    @overload
    def f(self, a: str) -> str:...

    def f(self, a) -> str | int:
        return a

class B(A):
    # Mypy: Signature of "f" incompatible with supertype "A"
    # Superclass:
    #   @overload def f(self, a: int) -> int
    #   @overload def f(self, a: str) -> str
    # Subclass:
    #   def f(self, a: int) -> int
    def f(self, a: int) -> int:
        return super().f(a)
```

If you are sure about your signature you can ask mypy to ignore the
override error with `type: ignore[override]` which ignore only the override error:

```
class C(A):
    def f(self, a: int) -> int:  # type: ignore[override]
        return super().f(a)

C().f(3)  # Mypy: OK
C().f('3')  # Mypy: Argument 1 to "f" of "C" has incompatible type    
            # "str"; expected "int" [arg-type]
```

Another solution with overload:

```
class C(A):
    @overload
    def f(self, a: int) -> int: ...

    @overload
    def f(self, a: str) -> str:...

    def f(self, a: int | str) -> int | str:
        return super().f(a)
```

Another one with `TypeVar` which works in this simple case:

```
T = TypeVar("T", int, str)

class B(A):

    def f(self, a: T) -> T:
        return super().f(a)
```

Note: You can ignore every single Mypy error with `ignore[error]`.
To know the error of Mypy you should launch mypy with `--show-error-codes`.

Comment: Thanks - I knew `type: ignore`, but not `type: ignore[override]` which is obviously better.

Comment: Could you maybe add an example *how* one would override your `A.f` correctly? Is replacing `int` by `int | str` enough? Or would you have to define a `TypeVar` to make sure the output type matches the input type?

Comment: I edit my answer to show alternatives to my example case.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that while one *can* tell MyPy to ``ignore`` partial method override, it's an actual type error that breaks [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and leaves the program inconsistently typed.

Comment: Yes, this is the type ignore karma.

Comment: @hussic does your "Another solution with overload" mean I can (but also have to) simply copy all the `@overloads` of the original function in case I do not find a simple superset expression? Can I inherit the `@overloads` somehow?